# TableView: Separator of cell change with different thickness when scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, render, list-separator

**This is a problem with the separator of UITableView in applications, which not support iPhone 6/6 Plus resolution.**

**Problem**
You have an application which works well on iPhone <= 5s. But on iPhone 6 or 6 Plus (device or simulator), the separators have a different thickness, and they change the thickness randomly when you scrolling the table as the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason**
The problem is that your app doesn’t support native resolution for the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. Therefore it gets scaled up which results in the flickering.

**Solution**
Open you .plist file and add this key & value

```
Renders with edge antialiasing: YES
```

This is getting from https://icodeios.wordpress.com/2017/05/04/first-blog-post/ and it's worked for me :)